# "disk drive for /mnt/ab37b9d4/9510-4480-aa84-d5f598aa1d92 is not ready yet or not present"

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

Few weeks ago I inserted a secondary internal disk "Western Digital 2TB Purple". It was working fine until I missed with the mounting and access permissions.

Now every time the system boots I get this error

> The disk drive for /mnt/ab37b9d4/9510-4480-aa84-d5f598aa1d92 is not
>   ready yet or not present
>
> continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery

This error keeps appearing even after I removed the new hard disk from the case "unplugged the power and data cables"

What exactly this error mean and How I can get rid of this message or at least make the system skip it automatically?

*There is no important data in the secondary hard disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably get this message because you disconnected that disc while it is still mounted when the system is booting.

This could work for you:

During boot write down the UUID of the drive and press S to skip mounting the drive.
Open the terminal window and type:
sudo gedit /etc/fstab

Locate the entry with the UUID you wrote down and put a dash (#) before that line to disable it. The file will look something like this and I highlighted the line that I disabled: (In this case the UUID is `15DB122A7DAE9399`)

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>

proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0
#Entry for /dev/sda1 :
UUID=31b7ed42-80c5-4d3e-ab89-fd5fb6cbc7df /..........
#Entry for /dev/sdc5 :
#UUID=15DB122A7DAE9399 /......... #This line
#Entry for /dev/sda5 :
UUID=db6830a1-c2f8-4f7a-b04b-3b3662c2455d none swap sw 0 0
```

Source:

[Ubuntuforums.org](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1507558)

Answer (score 0):

"/mnt/ab37b9d4/9510-4480-aa84-d5f598aa1d92" It is happened on Mount error or file corrupt. You just put a live disk and try "fsck" or restart pc ESC key, the choose ubuntu advance option then use FSCK. if anything does not work.

USE Live CD and go to fstab and edit /mnt/ab.. in permanently add into fstab.

External Hard disk is not mounted on Your pc so you have to add on Fstab then try if it not work try other linux pc and safely remove and try